# How can we only plot grid in X direction?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can we only plot grid in X direction? Could we change "grid=both" to "grid=..."?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  domain=0:2*pi,
  samples=200,
  no marks,
  xticklabels={-2$\pi$,-1.5$\pi$,...$\pi$,2$\pi$},
  xtick={-6.2832,-4.7124,...,6.2832},
  x post scale=1.5,
  ytick={-3,-2,-1,...,2,3},
  ymax=3]
 \addplot {(2*cos(\x r)- cos(2*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_3$};
 \addplot {(3*cos(\x r)- cos(3*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_4$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: So you want a bunch of parallel horizontal lines?  If that is the case, use `\foreach`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have the keys `xmajorgrids`, `xminorgrids`, `ymajorgrids`, `yminorgrids`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
  xmajorgrids=true,
  domain=0:2*pi,
  samples=200,
  no marks,
  xticklabels={-2$\pi$,-1.5$\pi$,...$\pi$,2$\pi$},
  xtick={-6.2832,-4.7124,...,6.2832},
  x post scale=1.5,
  ytick={-3,-2,-1,...,2,3},
  ymax=3]
 \addplot {(2*cos(\x r)- cos(2*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_3$};
 \addplot {(3*cos(\x r)- cos(3*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_4$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{axis}[
  ymajorgrids=true,
  domain=0:2*pi,
  samples=200,
  no marks,
  xticklabels={-2$\pi$,-1.5$\pi$,...$\pi$,2$\pi$},
  xtick={-6.2832,-4.7124,...,6.2832},
  x post scale=1.5,
  ytick={-3,-2,-1,...,2,3},
  ymax=3]
 \addplot {(2*cos(\x r)- cos(2*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_3$};
 \addplot {(3*cos(\x r)- cos(3*\x r))} node[below, green] {$K_4$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can we place the tikz figure surrounded by text?

Comment: @EdenHarder Do you mean that the text wraps around the figure? If so, take a look at the [wrapfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) package; of not, please explain in more detail your intent.